# Can send mail but can't receive SMTP failure

Tags: email, smtp, postfix-mta

I've got dedicated server to run all my sites from.

I created domain and updated all DNS records to this server, everything is fine and propagated however when i try and receive mail nothing happens but it can send.

I went to dnsstuff.com and this is the error i got...

> All connections to Mailservers port 25 have failed. The standard port
>   for SMTP transactions is 25, so your servers should be operating on
>   that port. It is recommended that it be fixed in order for your mail
>   service to operate properly. The Mail Servers that failed are:
>
> xx.xxx.xxx.xxx | failed message send with: failed cx open with: failed socket connect with: Operation now in progress

/*****************
UPDATE
*****************/

Running a linux box using centOS.

The mailserver being used is, I believe, Postfix.

How do i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your firewall configuration on your server. If you can send from localhost (that is, direclty from your server), but mail can't be delivered from remote servers to your box, your firewall is the best bet to look at. Basically port 25 should be open to any IP. It's hard to give you specific details on how to configure your firewall, as you do not specify your OS and dikstribution. Most Linux distro's run some flavour of iptables. If iptables is what you have, you could try this command from the command line:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
```

Before you open up your firewall, you might want to dive into configuring postfix. It would not be nice to the rest of the world if you started running an open relay. That will get your server blacklisted in no time. [This artice on the postfix website](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html) will give you a decent start.

Comment: It was the firewall. Thanks for your input.